# HATEOAS principal in retrofit? link to resources?

Tags: java, android, retrofit, hateoas

How can I use the HATEOAS principal in retrofit? Is there any way to use links in retrofit? Or should I parse it on my own?

```
links: [4]
0:  {
rel: "self"
href: "https://localhost/api/product/9"
}-
1:  {
rel: "comp"
href: "https://localhost/api/product/19/comp"
}-
2:  {
rel: "eval"
href: "https://localhost/api/product/19/eval"
}
```

My general question is, how can I use links to resource (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HATEOAS)? Is there any possibility? 
For example how can i invoke the "comp" href to the resource and get i parsed Java-Object (from JSON) return?

Comment: you can check out my HATEOAS with Retrofit code here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33404734/

Comment: From 2013: https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/333#issue-20454355

Answer (score 0):

Retrofit 2 has the `@Url` annotation for that.

Example:

```
public interface TempoRestApi {
    @GET("worklogs/issue/{issueKey}")
    Call<IssueWorklogResponse> getIssueWorklog(@Path("issueKey") String issueKey, @Query("from") String date, @Query("to") String end);

    @GET
    Call<IssueWorklogResponse> getIssueWorklog(@Url String url);
}
```

The first method is a normal retrofit `@GET` call. The response of that one has metadata that gives an absolute URL to the next page of results:

```
"metadata": {
    "count": 50,
    "offset": 0,
    "limit": 50,
    "next": "https://api.tempo.io/core/3/worklogs/issue/KEY-1?from=2020-01-01&to=2020-12-31&offset=50&limit=50"
  }
```

The 2nd one can be used with the returned `next` link that the first call gives.